# cloud HSM provision in IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am creating the cloud HSM resource in IBM Cloud.

I have given the info while creation of cloud hsm :
Network interface
Private VLAN: name of vplan
Private Subnet: subnet name

but I am getting an error: A backend VLAN is required but was not provided.

Any help ?

Comment: Please provide the request that you are using to see where is the error.

Comment: when I am clicking on create but I am getting the pop up with below error msg.
msg : A backend VLAN is required but was not provided.

Comment: I meant that you have to provide the rest api call and the payload you are using to see if it is correct. But you can try setting the Network interface Private VLAN or Subnet with the id and not with the name.

Comment: I have tried using private vlan. Now I am able to create the cloud hsm. One another issues was their that has been fixed by support team